# How to initialise an array of objects in iOS for MVVM

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, mvvm

I have a ViewModel class defined as below:

```
@interface MVVMViewModel : NSObject  
{  

}  

- (instancetype)initWithHomeItems;  

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *itemName;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *itemDesc; 


@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *itemLabel;
```

And in my ViewController class, I want to initialize an array with items including only itemName and desc as objects and exclude itemLabel. So how do I achieve this?

i.e., something like, NSMutableArray *itemList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:mvvmViewModel.itemName,...]; which means in my first index of array I want both name and desc and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you add the `MVVMViewModel` to the array? I know you said you don't want the `itemLabel` in the array, but why not.

Comment: Label is just a text label, which I don't want to store in my Model later.

Comment: Then don't save it in you model at all. Just saving the two string defeats the hole purpose of using model classes at all.

Comment: can you please elaborate. I did not get you.!

Comment: Well if you not going to use the model to keep your data en copy only the `itemName` and `itemDesc` into arrays then why use a model class at all. You can just use two array and passes to around. And if you are not using the  `itemLabel` at all, then why add to the model in the first place.